# Leveraging express server all() method

Tags: express

Recently going through the documentation of express framework, I found a method "all()" on an express server.
   If I understand it correct, it is used to prefetch the object on which a CRUD operation request if arrives later, the response time would reduce since it's been prefetched.
  Correct me if my understanding is wrong. 
  But I need to know the potential use cases on a real life scenario. What kind of resources could be prefetched and what are the trade offs to bear in mind while doing so?

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand it correct, it is used to prefetch the object on which a CRUD operation request if arrives later

`all` is generic and doesn't have any particular purpose prescribed for it within express. IMHO it's mostly useless and can be replaced by the more straightforward `app.use` which is nearly identical.

`app.all` just means use the callback handler on any HTTP request method, vs the standard `app.get`, `app.post`, `app.put`, etc (one per HTTP method name).